# What is the equation for this graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

Here is what `y(x) = -x+100` graph looks like:

[image]

I am trying to change this equation, so that the graph becomes a curve which still crosses the axis Y at (0,100) and axis X at (100,0):

[image]

Can anybody give me a hint on this?

Comment: That depends on how curved you want. There's a whole family of functions you could construct passing through points $(0,100)$ and $(100,0)$.

Comment: It doesn't matter, however curved it is - there will be a variable to make it more/less curved. I just can't remember the equation to make it curved.

Comment: There are an infinite number of curves which would fit your requirement. I just give you the first coming to my mind : y = 100 - 10 Sqrt[x].

Comment: @astralmaster: You can use a quadratic, cubic, quartic and other equations. Regards

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B-x%2B100+%2B+x%28x-100%29%2F120%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C100%7D%5D

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B-80+%2B+14400+%2F+%28x%2B80%29%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C100%7D%5D

Comment: Than you all for help and examples!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to choose a *third point* $(a,b),\ \ b\in(0,100)$, what your curve also contains, and then construct a *quadratic* function to fit these $3$ points, using
$$ \begin{aligned} p_0(x) &:=\frac{(x-a)(x-100)}{(-a)(-100)} \\ 
p_a(x) &:=\frac{x(x-100)}{a(a-100)} \\
p_{100}(x) &:=\frac{x(x-a)}{100(100-a)}
\end{aligned}$$
These satisfy $p_i(j)=1$ if $i=j$ and $p_i(j)=0$ if $i\ne j$ for $i,j\in\{0,a,100\}$. So, a quadratic curve can be obtained as
$$f(x):=100\cdot p_0(x)+b\cdot p_a(x)+0\cdot p_{100}(x)\,.$$